# Pixel data incorrect with alpha

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, scikit-learn, alpha

I am loading in an image with alpha and am confused at the data I am see to represent each pixel. I am splitting the pixel to get each b,g,r,a band respectively and am confused with my output when loaded into a data set as seen below:

Pixel ---------------------B-band---------G-band----------R-band---------------A-band

[image]

Why are my white pixels in the r band (4th column) 254 and not 255?
Why are the alpha values ranging from 0 to 255 and not 0 to 1?

Another interesting note is that where the alpha is set to 0 (transparent) I am confused as to why the pixels being given a color and alternately why opaque pixels are displayed as white and not transparent?
[image]

Code:

```
img = cv2.imread('/Volumes/EXTERNAL/ClassifierImageSets/Origional_2.png',-1)
b,g,r,a = cv2.split(img)
    test = pd.DataFrame({'bBnad':b.flat[:],'gBnad':g.flat[:],'rBnad':r.flat[:],'Alpha':a.flat[:]})
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', 4):
        print(test)
```

Comment: Alpha values range from 0 to 255, because that lets you also have partial transparency. Fully transparent pixels are invisible, so it doesn't matter what value they have. You'd have to investigate the code and possibly question the author of whatever software produced that image in the first place.

Comment: "why opaque pixels are displayed as white and not transparent" -- quite likely because whatever it is you're using to display the image is showing it on a white background (so the background shows through in the transparent bits).

Comment: @DanMašek I would agree with you but my classifier picks the pixel that should be null up as white (255,255,255)

Comment: How is your classifier implemented (as in, how does it handle the alpha channel) ? Perhaps you have to do some per-processing...